# XML parser to CSV

Tags: php, xml, csv

How can I parse xml to csv in php ? Can any one help me with this.

here is my sample code

```
$parseFile = simplexml_load_file('form.xml','SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$filename = 'form.csv';
$f = fopen($filename,'w');

foreach ($parseFile->xpath("//field/label[1]") as $node ){
$node = [];
 fputcsv($f,(array)$node);

}
fclose($f);
```

Comment: you will need to define your headers

Comment: the form.xml is my header

Answer (score 1):

Your script cannot automatically identify it is supposed to be a csv file just by naming a file with a csv extension.   If you want it to output as a csv file, you will need to define your ***output*** headers, like so.

This needs to go on the top of the file:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=form.csv');
```

**Edit**: including the rest of the code, including some minor syntax changes

```
$f = fopen('php://output','w');

foreach ($parseFile->xpath("//field/label[1]") as $node ){
$node = [];
 fputcsv($f,array($node));

}
fclose($f);
```

Comment: the csv is wokring but no data thrown in the csv

Comment: put the headers at the top of your code.  If your xml output was providing data before this should work. I'll edit this to make it a little clearer.

Comment: its not working the error message is array to string conversion error

Comment: Okay, the problem is not with the csv.  It 's with your query.  can you get it to spit out an HTML file first?  in other words, try removing the headers and instead of the fputcsv, just echo the rows.  That should be your first step.  Also if you can share some of the xml file, that might help, so we can see if the xpath is actually returning anything at all